# Python typing deprecation

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

The latest [typing docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) has a lot of deprecation notices like the following:

```
class typing.Deque(deque, MutableSequence[T])
A generic version of collections.deque.

New in version 3.5.4.

New in version 3.6.1.

Deprecated since version 3.9: collections.deque now supports []. See PEP 585 and Generic Alias Type.
```

What does this means? Should we not use the generic type `Deque` (and several others) anymore? I've looked at the references and didn't connect the dots (could be because I'm an intermediate Python user).

Comment: Did you read PEP 585? Sounds like the explanation might be there.

Comment: @blorgon I have, and updated my question stating that. For some reason, a mod decided my previous comment should be deleted so this note is merely for the record `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means that you should be transitioning to using built-in types / types from the standard library instead of the ones provided by `typing`. So for example `collections.deque[int]` instead of `typing.Deque[int]`. The same for `list`, `tuple`, etc. So `tuple[int, str]` is the preferred way.

Comment: This is so much clearer than "_collections.deque now supports []_", which means absolutely nothing to me.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar - the point the note was trying to make is that using [<type>] is used to signify the contained type for a container. Since collections.deque now supports [] it means that you can use it as a type hint. I accept it isn't that clear though :-)

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 I can't speak for others, but `[]` means empty list to me. IMO, a clearer note would be "_collections.deque now supports generic typing, please migrate to it_".

Answer (score 4):

See [PEP585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/) and [Generic Alias Type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-genericalias).

Changes in Python 3.9 remove the necessity for a parallel type hierarchy in the `typing` module, so that you can just use `collections.deque` directly when annotating a deque-like type.

For example, it means that annotating a deque of ints like

```
def foo(d: typing.Deque[int]):
    ...
```

Should be changed to:

```
def foo(d: collections.deque[int]):
    ...
```

Comment: You could use `def foo(d: collections.deque)` before, the news about 3.9 is the ability to use `def foo(d: collections.deque[sometype])`