# Type annotations: tuple type vs union type

Tags: python, union-types, pylance, type-annotation

```
def func(df_a: pd.DataFrame, df_b: pd.DataFrame) -> (pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame):
```

Pylance is advising to modify this line with two solution proposed. What would be the pros and cons of each one if there is any significant difference?

> Tuple expression not allowed in type annotation
>
> Use Tuple[T1, ..., Tn] to indicate a tuple type or Union[T1, T2] to indicate a union type

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## 2023 edit

In newer versions of Python (>=3.10), you should use:

- `tuple[A, B, C]` instead of `Tuple[A, B, C]` (yes, that's the built-in `tuple` function)
- `A | B` instead of `Union[A, B]`

The answer itself is still relevant, even if the newer style makes the difference between `Tuple`/`tuple` and `Union`/`|` more apparent.

## Original answer

They mean different things:

- `Tuple[A, B, C]` means that the function returns a three-element tuple with the A B C data types:

```
def f() -> Tuple[str, int, float]:
    return 'hello', 10, 3.33
```

- `Union[A, B]` means that the function returns an object of either A or B data type:

```
import random 

def f() -> Union[str, int]:
    if random.random() > 0.5:
        return 'hello'
    else:
        return 10
```

In your case, it looks like you want to use `Tuple[pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame]`.

Comment: Thank you for this clear answer !

Comment: You should use `tuple` rather than `Tuple` here, as the latter is [depreciated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66738753/python-typing-deprecation).

Answer (score 1):

A union type wouldn't make sense here since the types are the same.

If you want to indicate that a tuple is being returned, you'd use `Tuple[pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame]` in older versions of Python, or `tuple[pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame]` in newer versions of Python. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65777001/3000206) for more information.